# Why is there a Mandelbrot hidden in this sequence?

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals

I was experimenting a bit with tetration escape visualization and tried to visualize the following equation on the complex plane:

$$z_{n+1} = z_{0}^{\sin(z_{n})}$$

This sequence visualized looks like this:
[image: sin]

I noticed between $7.8-0.11i$ and $8.03+0.11i$ there was a Mandelbrot set hidden between all the other mess:

[image: mandelbrot]

Also between $-4.81-0.15i$ and $4.61+0.15i$ there is a Mandelbrot-like structure:
[image: mandelbrot-like]

How comes the Mandelbrot set randomly appears in there?

Comment: Notice that $\,2.5\pi\approx 7.85\,$ which means that $\,\sin(x+2.5\pi)=\cos(x)\approx 1-x^2/2\,$

Comment: I am unable by computing in a loop $Z(n+1)=z_0^{\sin Z(n)}$ with $Z(0)=z_0$ to find something ressembling even partially to Mandelbrot set...with the kind of $z_0$ values you give.

Comment: Could you place an image on some server that would indicated what you mean by "Mandelbrot set out of a mess"... or insert a program in the langage you use ?

Comment: I now have enough reputation to post images and links. I made a tool to visualize it, you can find it here: https://github.com/GraxCode/towerpower/ Make sure to select "sin" mode.

Comment: $z_{0}$ is the point on the complex plane. I visualize the value $z$ as a color after enough iterations that the change is below 0.00000001.

Comment: That second "Mandelbrot-like" structure is surprisingly adorable.  Just saying.

Comment: Looks like a cute crab, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you work exactly as for the usual Mandelbrot set but with a formula which is no longer $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c.$

Comment: exactly. $z_{n+1} = z_{0}^{z_{n}}$ would be the tetration escape sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider iteration of $z \mapsto c^{\sin(z)}$ near $c$:

$$z \mapsto c^{\sin(c + z)} - c$$

The Taylor series near $z = 0$ is (via Wolfram Alpha):

$$ z \mapsto \left(c^{\sin(c)} - c\right) \\ 
 + \left(\log(c) c^{\sin(c)} \cos(c)\right) z \\
 + \left(\frac{1}{2} \log(c) c^{\sin(c)} \left(\log(c) \cos(c)^2 - \sin(c)\right)\right) z^2 \\
 + O(z^3)
$$

Locally ($z$ small), the non-linearity is dominated by the $z^2$ term (as higher order terms will be much smaller).  This means miniature quadratic Mandelbrot set copies may appear.  Completing the square to the form $z \mapsto a(z + b)^2 + d$ gives:

$$
ab^2 + d = c^{\sin(c)} - c \\
2ab = \log(c) c^{\sin(c)} \cos(c) \\
a = \frac{1}{2} \log(c) c^{\sin(c)} \left(\log(c) \cos(c)^2 - \sin(c)\right)
$$

[Affine conjugation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050101/every-quadratic-polynomial-is-conjugate-to-one-of-the-polynomial-z2t) via $z \mapsto z - b$ and $z \mapsto \frac{z}{a}$ gives the form $z \mapsto z^2 + C$ where $C = a (d + b)$ which expands to:

$$ C = \frac{1}{2} \log(c) \left(c^{\sin(c)} - c\right) c^{\sin(c)} \left(\log(c) \cos(c)^2 - \sin(c)\right) \\ - \left(\frac{1}{2} \log(c) c^{\sin(c)} \cos(c)\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \log(c) c^{\sin(c)} \cos(c) $$

Solving numerically for $C = 0$ gives ([via Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%20log%28c%29%20%28c%5E%28sin%28c%29%29%20-%20c%29%20%28c%5E%28sin%28c%29%29%29%20%28log%28c%29%20cos%28c%29%5E2%20-%20sin%28c%29%29%20-%20%281%2F2%20log%28c%29%20c%5E%28sin%28c%29%29%20cos%28c%29%29%5E2%20%2B%201%2F2%20log%28c%29%20c%5E%28sin%28c%29%29%20cos%28c%29%20%3D%200)) a number of solutions including: $$c \approx 7.85398163397448\ldots$$

Solving numerically for $C = 0$ near $c = -4.7$ ([via Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5B%28c%5ESin%5Bc%5D%20Cos%5Bc%5D%20Log%5Bc%5D%29%2F2%20-%20%28c%5E%282%20Sin%5Bc%5D%29%20Cos%5Bc%5D%5E2%20Log%5Bc%5D%5E2%29%2F4%20%2B%20%28c%5ESin%5Bc%5D%20%28-c%20%2B%20c%5ESin%5Bc%5D%29%20Log%5Bc%5D%20%28Cos%5Bc%5D%5E2%20Log%5Bc%5D%20-%20Sin%5Bc%5D%29%29%2F2%20%3D%3D%200%2C%20%7Bc%2C%20-4.6%2C%20-4.8%7D%2C%20WorkingPrecision%20-%3E%2015%5D)) the solution: $$c \approx -4.71238898038469\ldots$$

These both correspond to mini-Mandelbrot islands with period $1$, there should also be mini-Mandelbrot islands corresponding to higher periods, for example I think there should be a period $3$ near $18.155$ (with $C \approx -1.754\ldots$).

Comment: Wow! Really nice explanation!